# Can I make a synchronous/blocking call via RabbitMQ using Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration

Imagine I have two Java apps, A and B, using Spring Integration's RabbitMQ support for communication.

Can I make a synchronous/blocking call from A to B? If so, how (roughly)?

---

Ideally, A has a Spring Integration Gateway which it invokes via e.g. a method called

```
Object doSomething(Object param)
```

Then it blocks while the Gateway sends on the message via RabbitMQ to a ServiceActivator on B, and B returns the return value, which eventually becomes the result of the doSomething() method.

It seems this may be possible, but the docs and other Stack Overflow questions don't seem to address this directly.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that's true. Exactly `Gateway` pattern implements that requirement.

Your client is blocked to wait the result from that gateway's method, but the underlying Integration flow can be `async`, `paralleled` etc.

Spring Integration AMQP provides the `<int-amqp:outbound-gateway>` for the blocking `request/reply` scenarios with RabbitMQ.

Of course the other, receiving side should take care of the `correlation` to send reply to the appropiriate `replyToAddress` from request message. The simples way to use `<int-amqp:inbound-gateway>` there.

Comment: Sweet - thank you! One point for clarification, I wasn't specific enough: I meant a *Messaging* Gateway, while in your reply you mostly mention Outbound/Inbound AMQP Gateways. It's probably all fine, I just hook up my Messaging Gateway's output channel as input to the AMQP Outbound Gateway - that's the entire setup you mean, right?

Comment: Correct. Feel free to ask more question